# blocking access by typing adress bar but php load only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a web page and I want to know if there is a way to block access to certain pages but reachable if PHP loads them. The idea is this; I have some modules that I `include()`; them with PHP. There will be no problem if users reach them by typing them into the address bar because they are managed with `$_SESSION` vars and they be seeing what they see in the included page but I just want to prevent that because if somebody discovers that link it is an uncomfortable view.

Comment: Can you share your code, so that we can look on to the problem ?

Comment: lookup .htaccess

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33999475/863110) question.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen there is no code mate. You want me to share a normal web page codes?

Comment: @clearshot66 thank you mate I will check.

Comment: @MoshFeu this is what exactly im looking for..

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer if anybody searches.

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location:../index.php');
    exit;
}
```

at this to the top of the page inside php tags.