# How do I prevent someone from visiting a page link Directly?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How do I prevent someone from visiting a page link Directly?

Say for example, i want to prevent people from visiting /blog/index.html directly. They can only visit the link if they come from /home/index.html

I've seen solutions in JavaScript and PHP but most of them look tedious to implement.

I have some HTML and CSS knowledge and have no knowledge on other languages, so what ever help you guys provide, make sure to explain it yeah?

I look forward to your answers! Thanks!

Comment: Authenticate them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent direct url access to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999475/prevent-direct-url-access-to-php-file)

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at it. Will try implementing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this from Michel's Duplicate Question Redirect. Thanks for the Answers!

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
// redirect them to your desired location
header('location:../index.php');
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this on the top of your `/blog/index.html`:

```
<?php if(str_replace("http://www.example.com", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != "/home/index.html"){echo"Error!";exit;}?>
```

But may be manipulable.

Comment: Thanks but Michel's link from above is what I implemented. Appreciate the effort! :)

Comment: Okay, no problem.