# Prevent direct access to .php files in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to prevent direct access to php files to prevent bot attack

It is completely shut down with the following htaccess code.
it didn't work for me

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/ 
(.*)\.php$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: How are humans gonna access those .php files if you prevent direct access?

Comment: You should only have access with url.

/folder/folder/example.php 
instead

the orientation

/example

Comment: You missed the `RewriteRule` syntex in the third line. ? It should be `RewriteRule 
 (.*)\.php$ /index.html [L] `

Comment: php code with this code cannot access each other.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Could you please be a bit specific?

Comment: a php file, b php file is included.

Clients cannot access b.php directly. But I want a.php file to reach b.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent direct url access to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999475/prevent-direct-url-access-to-php-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you want that just the server has access to your php files you can use this:

```
<Filesmatch "\.(php)$">
    Require local
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Never saw Required used with that keyword before, is this documented anywhere? Can’t find anything about this on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require (I think this might only be a partial solution, and `local` is supposed to be an environment variable here maybe? Then that would have to be set somewhere depending on where the request came from, I don’t think this is a standard/default one …?)

Comment: you are right. I couldnt find it too. but years ago i found it somewhere and it should test if it is the local server by ip.but its working on my site

Comment: I found the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html)