# How can I prevent users access pages directly via url?

Tags: php

I have a get edit button; <a href="edit_leave.php?delete=id); ?>,linking to an edit page. My problem is that have noticed user can edit other leave-types by just changing the id on the link; https://www.website.com/edit_leave.php?edit=11.

I have tried adding this script on top of the page:

```
<?phpif ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE, 403 );die( header( 'location: /404.php' ) );}?>.
```

How can i prevent this edit via URL?

Comment: Do these user have access to the item they are accessing? If not then you should write extra code to check if an user is authorized to edit/delete an item

Comment: Please refer the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999475/prevent-direct-url-access-to-php-file

Comment: @HARINDAVITHANA OP already saw that question as the snippet posted is an exact copy of one of the answers

Comment: @DarkBee My bad for not noticing. Apologies.

Comment: No problem, just pointing out

Comment: my problem is that despite adding the scripts i can still change the id and edit form linked to the id. am running on localhost

Comment: Well yeah, from what I can tell the initial questions uses mod_rewrite before executing the scripts. Did you read my initial comment?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this question. Do you a proper authentication/authorisation system in place? There's no way to discriminate access without that, unless you have a static IP address and you want to base it on that.

Comment: authorization and authentification are in place. let me give an example.  i have applied for a leavetype eg. annual leave, i have an option to cancel leave i.e href="index.php?cancel=<?php echo ($result->id); ?>. then there is a condition to hide the cancel button.. but a user can still access the leave via address bar using the link.

Comment: So you already have the logic built, currently used to decide if the button must be shown. Use that same logic to decide if the cancellation can be processed.

Comment: `<?phpif` does that even work? Is this a typo?